# DevExpress GridHitInfo on group row

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have drawn a checkbox in [devexpress grid group row](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument549) using the code below.

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Drawing;
using DevExpress.Utils.Drawing;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.ViewInfo;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Drawing;
//...
void gvWorkspaces_CustomDrawGroupRow(object sender, RowObjectCustomDrawEventArgs e) {
    GridGroupRowPainter groupRowPainter = (GridGroupRowPainter)e.Painter;
    GridGroupRowInfo info = (GridGroupRowInfo)e.Info;
    groupRowPainter.DrawGroupRowBackground(info);
    groupRowPainter.DrawObject(info);
    Rectangle checkRect = info.ButtonBounds;
    checkRect.X = e.Bounds.Right - checkRect.Width -4;
    DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, checkRect, true);
    e.Handled = true;
}
void DrawCheckBox(Graphics graphics, Rectangle r, bool Checked) {
    RepositoryItemCheckEdit edit = new RepositoryItemCheckEdit();
    CheckEditViewInfo info = (CheckEditViewInfo)edit.CreateViewInfo();
    info.EditValue = Checked;
    info.Bounds = r;
    info.CalcViewInfo(graphics);

    CheckEditPainter painter = (CheckEditPainter)edit.CreatePainter();
    ControlGraphicsInfoArgs args = new ControlGraphicsInfoArgs(info, new GraphicsCache(graphics), r);
    painter.Draw(args);
    args.Cache.Dispose();
}
```

However, I am having challenges in accessing the checkbox to tick and untick.

I tried to use GridHitInfo in GridView click event (as below). But I am not getting anything that could help me to access the checkbox.

```
void gvWorkspaces_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GridView view = (GridView)sender;
    Point pt = view.GridControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    GridHitInfo info = view.CalcHitInfo(pt);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Balan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the following approach:

```
RepositoryItemCheckEdit edit;
CheckEditViewInfo editInfo;
CheckEditPainter editPainter;
//...
    edit = new RepositoryItemCheckEdit();
    editInfo = (CheckEditViewInfo)edit.CreateViewInfo();
    editPainter = (CheckEditPainter)edit.CreatePainter();
}
Hashtable checkedRows = new Hashtable();
Hashtable editorRects = new Hashtable();
void gvWorkspaces_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GridView view = (GridView)sender;
    Point pt = view.GridControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    GridHitInfo info = view.CalcHitInfo(pt);
    if(info.InRow) {
        Rectangle editorRect = (Rectangle)editorRects[info.RowHandle];
        if(editorRect.Contains(pt)) {
            object value = checkedRows[info.RowHandle]; 
            if(value == null)
                checkedRows[info.RowHandle] = true;
            else checkedRows.Remove(info.RowHandle);
            view.GridControl.Invalidate(editorRect);
        }
    }
}
void gvWorkspaces_CustomDrawGroupRow(object sender, RowObjectCustomDrawEventArgs e) {
    e.Painter.DrawObject(e.Info);
    GridGroupRowInfo info = (GridGroupRowInfo)e.Info;
    Rectangle checkRect = info.ButtonBounds;
    checkRect.X = e.Bounds.Right - checkRect.Width - 4;
    DrawCheckEdit(e.Graphics, checkRect, checkedRows[e.RowHandle] != null);
    editorRects[e.RowHandle] = checkRect; // cache rectangle
    e.Handled = true;
}
void DrawCheckEdit(Graphics graphics, Rectangle r, bool cheched) {
    editInfo.EditValue = cheched;
    editInfo.Bounds = r;
    editInfo.CalcViewInfo(graphics);
    using(GraphicsCache cache = new GraphicsCache(graphics)) {
        editPainter.Draw(new ControlGraphicsInfoArgs(editInfo, cache, r));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am seeing the group row text become invisible when I click the check box. Is this a common behavior of the solution?

Comment: @balan: It is strange... works fine to me. Anyway, use [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=question) rather than StackOverflow